# How to iterate over a map and match its key values with enum class members?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a quick question.

Is there any trick to iterate through the keys of a map and use them to access an enumerate class items.

For example, lets say we have the Color class as defined below.

```
enum class Color {blue = 0, green = 1, yellow = 2};

unordered_map<string, string> mp {
  {"blue",""},
  {"green",""},
  {"yellow",""},
  {"red", ""}
 };

for (auto e: mp) {
   if(e.first.compare("blue") ==0) { // e.first == "blue"
       e.second = fGetVal(Color::blue); 
    } else if (e.first.compare("green") ==0) { 
       e.second = fGetVal(Color::green); 
    } else if (e.first.compare("yellow") ==0) {
       e.second = fGetVal(Color::yellow); 
    } else {
       cout<<"the requested color is not supported!"
    }
}

//  assume fGetVal() takes the enum class type as input and returns it value as a string
```

1. Is there a better approach than using if/else-if to call method fGetVal?
2. More specifically trying to use a variable name for accessing enum class elements something like Color::e.first

Comment: `Is there any trick to iterate through the keys of a map and use them to access an enumerate class items.` yes. it's the map itself is meant to do that trick.

Comment: `e.first == "blue"` reads a lot easier

Comment: This feels like there's an unneeded layer of indirection involved here. You have a logical static mapping that associates `"yellow"` to some other `string`. If you had that stored in a constant somewhere, you could just do `e.second = colorStringMap.at(e.first);`

Comment: You could just map from the color name to the proper `Color` directly. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/socK33jaK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean way to do is is to pre-cache the results of `fGetVal()` in a map and just do a simple lookup:

```
const unordered_map<string, string> colorStringsMap = {
 {"blue", fGetVal(Color::blue)},
 {"green", fGetVal(Color::green)},
 {"yellow", fGetVal(Color::yellow)},
};


int main() {
  unordered_map<string, string> mp {
    {"blue",""},
    {"green",""},
    {"yellow",""},
    {"red", ""}
   };

  for (auto& e: mp) {
    try {
      e.second = colorStringsMap.at(e.first);
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range) {
      cout <<"the requested color is not supported!";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to convert user input input a Color enum

```
enum class Color { blue = 0, green = 1, yellow = 2 };

unordered_map<string, Color> mp{
  {"blue",Color::blue},
  {"green",Color::green},
  {"yellow",Color::yellow},
};

string col = getUserInput();
auto find = mp.find(col);
if (find == mp.end()) {
    cout << "bad color";
}
else {
    auto encol = find->second;
}
```

Comment: This is not the use-case. 
i need to iterate through map elements and call a specific method (given as an interface to update the value of the map). The other way is slightly different.
One approach could be iterating through the enum class values, but wonder to check if there is a way to use a variable to access enum class members.